# Replace the value in column according to the order in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Now I have a dataframe. I want to replace the value in column `C`, when column `A` and `B` both find matches. The replace rule is determined by the order in the strings in a list `L = ['x','y','z'].`

1. For rows 0 and 1, column `A` and `B` are matched, then column  `C` has `x` and `y`. `x` comes before `y` according to the list `L`. Then `y` is replaced with `x`.
2. For row 2, column `A` and `B` don't find matches, leave column `C` along
3. For rows 3 and 4, column `A` and `B` are matched, then column  `C` has `y` and `z`. `y` comes before `z` according to the list `L`. Then `z` is replaced with `y`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
L = ['x','y','z']

s1 = pd.Series(['a', 'c', 'x'])
s2 = pd.Series(['a', 'c', 'y'])
s3 = pd.Series(['a', 'd', 'z'])
s4 = pd.Series(['b', 'd', 'y'])
s5 = pd.Series(['b', 'd', 'z'])
    
df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2), list(s3), list(s4), list(s5)],  columns =  ['A', 'B', 'C'])
df


    A   B   C
0   a   c   x
1   a   c   y
2   a   d   z
3   b   d   y
4   b   d   z
```

Desired outcome:

```
    A   B   C
0   a   c   x
1   a   c   x
2   a   d   z
3   b   d   y
4   b   d   y
```

Comment: What if there is another row  at index `5` for example with values `b  d  x`. What will be the output in that case?

Comment: @Shubham Sharma Then row `3` and `4` will both be `b d x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `sort` the values of column `C` based on ordering in list `L`, then `group` the dataframe on columns `A, B` and `transform` column `C` using `first`:

```
# create mapping dict
# in order to impose ordering 
d = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(L)}

# map and sort the values
s = df.assign(k=df['C'].map(d)).sort_values('k')

# group and transform
df['C'] = s.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].transform('first')
```

---

```
   A  B  C
0  a  c  x
1  a  c  x
2  a  d  z
3  b  d  y
4  b  d  y
```